# Warning and runtime error during time handling

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The following code should be working (it's an accepted answer in stackoveflow), but somehow I get two warnings and as a consequence I get a segmentation fault. What's wrong?

```
time_t timer;
char buffer[25];
struct tm* tm_info;

time(&timer);
tm_info = localtime(&timer);

strftime(buffer, 25, "%Y:%m:%d%H:%M:%S", tm_info);
```

bead.c:61: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
bead.c:63: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âstrftimeâ

```
line 61 is tm_info = localtime(&timer);
and line 63 is strftime(buffer, 25, "%Y:%m:%d%H:%M:%S", tm_info);
```

Comment: Which compiler? You're example is practically the same as the one in the docs: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... The compiler thinks `localtime` returns an integer and `strftime` does not exist?

Are you sure you're including  `<time.h>`?

Comment: What an amateur mistake! Thank you

Comment: In my case, I included sys/time.h and not time.h... Get that warning and a segfault...

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it in "gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) " and everything worked fine!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i don't include time.h, this code segfaults, if i do it does not segfault.

Without time.h, your compiler does not know the signature of the function and assumes it is a function that returns an int (if my memories are good).

Long story short, include time.h